# How do I split the final component of a &Path at a specific character?

Tags: rust, filenames

I have a `&Path` and I need to split the final component filename into two parts at the first colon.

I can get the final component as an `&OsStr` (`path.file_name()`) - but then I'm a bit stuck on actually doing anything with the contents.  The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html) gives me a few options:

- `to_str()` or `to_string_lossy()`, which either fail or return a corrupted string if it's not UTF-8 (which isn't guaranteed!)
- `to_bytes()` or `to_cstring()`, but they're marked as deprecated since Rust 1.6.
- Right at the bottom I see `impl OsStrExt` with an `as_bytes()` method.  `OsStrExt` is `std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt` which is described as "Unix-specific extensions to `OsStr`".  However [std::os::unix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/) is apparently "Experimental extensions to std for Unix platforms."

Have I missed anything more standard?

As it happens I'm happy to limit to Unix for this application, so the `OsStrExt::as_bytes` looks like the best option for now; but is it really still experimental, or is the documentation out of date?

Comment: What you want to do with the contents (like `file_name`)?

Comment: I'm doing things with messages in [Maildirs](https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html); the filename is an unspecified unique part followed by `':'` and some flag characters.  I want to examine or modify the flags, without touching the unique portion.

Comment: *is it really still experimental* — if it's not `unstable`, you should be able to count on it existing for all of Rust 1.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way to deal with file system paths because not all platforms have the same rules regarding the representation and validity of paths.

On Unix-based systems (Linux, Mac OS X, etc.), paths are a sequence of bytes (`u8`) that cannot contain null bytes. The `std::os::unix` module is available on those platforms. Although the module's description says "experimental", most of it is stable, so the stable features are guaranteed to remain available in future Rust 1.x releases.

> NOTE: Since the question and this answer were written, the module's description was amended and it's no longer described as experimental.

On Windows NT, paths are a sequence of 16-bit words (usually interpreted as UTF-16 code units), which may contain unpaired surrogates. Internally, Rust converts these paths to [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) (which is just UTF-8 with the addition of allowing the encoding of unpaired surrogates, U+D800–U+DFFF). The [`std::os::windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/windows/index.html) module is available on this platform. It provides [*different* `OsStrExt` and `OsStringExt` traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/windows/ffi/index.html) that let you encode an `OsStr` to potentially ill-formed UTF-16 or decode a potentially ill-formed UTF-16 path to an `OsString`, but don't provide access to the WTF-8 representation.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my doubts perfectly!

Comment: On windows there are both ASCII and Unicode versions of a lot of functions. Possibly going via the ASCII encoded versions, the conversion to the internal WTF-8 could be left to the system libraries instead of finding an approach within Rust. Not sure, which choice is better, though. In one embedded project we created a portable facility which works both for *nix and windows (desktop, CE, ...) by writing a set of classes working similar to the respective objects in the .NET library. We were happy with that.

Comment: Rust uses the Unicode versions, because the "ANSI" versions don't let you use characters outside the "ANSI" code page, thus there may be files your application couldn't access. I suspect that Rust converts potentially ill-formed UTF-16 (WTF-16?) to WTF-8 because the vast majority of paths are legal UTF-16, and thus can be converted to legal UTF-8, which means those paths can be accessed as UTF-8 like the rest of the strings in Rust.